# How to disable Redis log during command execution

Tags: php, symfony, redis

When I am running Symfony command (with `bin/console`) I'm getting Redis logs in the output.

For example:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Item

[2017-10-18 13:26:47] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "{key}" ({type}) {"key":"%5BAppBundle%5CEntity%5CItem%40%5BAnnot%5D%5D%5B1%5D","type":"array","exception":null}
[2017-10-18 13:26:47] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "{key}" ({type}) {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DAppBundle%5CEntity%5CItem%24property_1%40%5BAnnot%5D%5D%5B1%5D","type":"integer","exception":null}
[2017-10-18 13:26:47] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "{key}" ({type}){"key":"%5B%5BC%5DAppBundle%5CEntity%5CItem%24property_2%40%5BAnnot%5D%5D%5B1%5D","type":"integer","exception":null}
Generating entity "AppBundle\Entity\Item"
[2017-10-18 13:26:47] cache.WARNING: Failed to save key "{key}" ({type}) {"key":"%5B%5BC%5DAppBundle%5CEntity%5CItem%24property_3%40%5BAnnot%5D%5D%5B1%5D","type":"integer","exception":null}
... and at least 100 more

 > backing up Item.php to Item.php~
 > generating AppBundle\Entity\Item
```

This makes the actual output of commands hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `snc_redis.phpredis.default` / `Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Phpredis\Client` service is just a wrapper around the original `\Redis` class to add the logging.

You can either turn off logging for a instance of the configuration, or use the Redis class directly.

The logging is usually set to "%kernel.debug%", which should avoid logging in env=prod.

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
            # usually "%kernel.debug%" to enable in dev
            logging: false
```

If you aren't using sncRedis, we'd need more info of what mechanism you are using to be able to help.